# Windows 10 'Save as' dialog missing This PC

Tags: windows-10

I have Windows 10. After some tweaks, I have noticed that **SOME** applications "save as" dialogs and "open file" dialogs have only Desktop folder and it has folders:
1. User profile
2. Network

Notepad.exe have ALL items in Save as dialog (through Navigation panel):
1. This PC
2. Desktop
3. Documents
4. Downloads
5. Music
6. Pictures
7. Videos
8. Local disk С
9. Local disk D
 but Firefox has only Desktop folders: User profile and Network.
Is there a way to restore normal folder displaying?

Comment: What tweaks exactly?

Comment: What are those **Some** applications ?

Comment: Are you joking? Why did you ask it? I have written: "Notepad.exe have ALL items in Save as dialog (through Navigation panel): 1. This PC 2. Desktop 3. Documents 4. Downloads 5. Music 6. Pictures 7. Videos 8. Local disk С 9. Local disk D but Firefox has only Desktop folders: User profile and Network"

Comment: @Ramhound I have used several, one of them like here: [link](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6015-pc-folders-add-remove-windows-10-a.html)

Answer (score -1):

To recover "This PC" in file dialog window, I had to **remove** Attributes from Registry key *HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\ShellFolder*
Details [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5352-pc-navigation-pane-add-remove-windows-10-a.html).